# How to select a JTable column on selection of header in Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable

I found a code to select a column on click of JTable header by applying a mouse listener on the header. But unfortunately, on click of a table cell whole JTable column is selected and the selection strategy is not reversed as before. Instead it selects the whole column on selection of a cell.

[image]

Code:-

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.JTableHeader;

public class HeaderLocation {  
    private JTable getTable() {  
        int rows = 32, cols = 4;  
        String[] colIds = { "column 1", "column 2", "column 3", "column 4" };  
        Object[][] data = new Object[rows][cols];  
        for(int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {  
            for(int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {  
                data[row][col] = "item " + (row*cols+col+1);  
            }  
        }  
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, colIds);  
        final JTable table = new JTable(model);  
        final JTableHeader header = table.getTableHeader();  
        table.setCellEditor(new CustomCellEditor());
        header.setReorderingAllowed(false);  
        header.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {  
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {  
                int col = header.columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());  
                System.out.printf("click cursor = %d%n",  
                                   header.getCursor().getType());  
                if(header.getCursor().getType() == Cursor.E_RESIZE_CURSOR)  
                    e.consume();  
                else {  
                    //System.out.printf("sorting column %d%n", col); 
                    table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
                    table.setRowSelectionAllowed(false);
                    table.clearSelection();
                    table.setColumnSelectionInterval(col,col);
                    //tableModel[selectedTab].sortArrayList(col);  
                }  
            }  
        });  


        return table;  
    }  

    private JMenuBar getMenuBar() {  
        final JMenu view = new JMenu("view");  
        ActionListener l = new ActionListener() {  
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {  
                JMenuItem item = (JMenuItem)e.getSource();  
                String className = item.getActionCommand();  
                changePLAF(className, view.getTopLevelAncestor());  
            }  
        };  
        UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo[] info = UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels();  
        for(int j = 0; j < info.length; j++) {  
            JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem(info[j].getName());  
            item.setActionCommand(info[j].getClassName());  
            item.addActionListener(l);  
            view.add(item);  
        }  
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();  
        menuBar.add(view);  
        return menuBar;  
    }  

    private void changePLAF(String className, Component c) {  
        try {  
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(className);  
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {  
            System.err.println("class not found: " + cnfe.getMessage());  
        } catch(InstantiationException ie) {  
            System.err.println("instantiation: " + ie.getMessage());  
        } catch(IllegalAccessException iae) {  
            System.err.println("illegal access: " + iae.getMessage());  
        } catch(UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ulafe) {  
            System.err.println("unsupported laf: " + ulafe.getMessage());  
        }  
        SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(c);  
    }  

    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        HeaderLocation test = new HeaderLocation();  
        JFrame f = new JFrame();  
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
        f.setJMenuBar(test.getMenuBar());  
        f.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(test.getTable()));  
        f.pack();  
        f.setLocation(200,200);  
        f.setVisible(true);  
    }  
}
```

CustomCellEditor.java

```
import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class CustomCellEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {

    public CustomCellEditor() {
        super(new JTextField());
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
        table.clearSelection();
        table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(false);
        table.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
        return super.getTableCellEditorComponent(table, value, isSelected, row, column);
        }

}
```

From the above code:-

1.) On click of header column is properly selected.
2.) But on click of a cell whole column is selected not only one cell as expected. I tried to invert Column selection but it's not working as expected.

Any help related with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

you would need to reverse code lines declared inside `header.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {` back

from

```
table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
table.setRowSelectionAllowed(false);
```

to

```
table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(false);
table.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
```

in 1st `mouse events` outside of `JTableHeader`

Comment: cell is selected1st. mouse events outside of JTableHeader, then after CellEditor started on 2nd click (if isn't this clickcountstart changed) and haven't something with JTable

Answer (score 3):

Your selection switching beetween columns and rows works. Your problem that you don't set your editor to table columns, because `setCellEditor()` method of `JTable` do another thing, [read about it](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setCellEditor%28javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor%29).

For adding your editor to columns, you need to replace `table.setCellEditor(new CustomCellEditor());` with :

```
    Enumeration<TableColumn> columns = table.getColumnModel().getColumns();
    while(columns.hasMoreElements()){
        columns.nextElement().setCellEditor(new CustomCellEditor());
    }
```

EDIT:

Now selectionMode switching when you select header, or start editing your table cell. You can add a mouseListenr to your table or change click count to start editing cell, for switching every time :

```
  table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
          public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {  
              table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(false);
              table.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
          }  
    });
```

[`setClickCountToStart()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultCellEditor.html#setClickCountToStart%28int%29)

Comment: Hi Actually on click of the header I need the column selection so it is working fine. But cell editor is introduced so that after when user will select a specific cell no column selection would come into picture. Which i tried in CustomCellEditor.

Answer (score 3):

**Add a mouse adapter to your JTable in main function:**

```
tableSet.getTableHeader().addMouseListener(getTableHeaderMouseAdapter(tableSet));
```

**The mouse adapter could be:**

```
protected static MouseAdapter getTableHeaderMouseAdapter(final JTable tableSet) {return new MouseAdapter(){
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            int c = tableSet.columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());
            tableSet.setColumnSelectionInterval(c, c);
            if(tableSet.getRowCount() > 0){
                tableSet.setRowSelectionInterval(0, tableSet.getRowCount()-1);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this easy solution. 
I think this is what you're looking for.

```
table.getTableHeader().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        int clickedIndex = table.convertColumnIndexToModel(table.columnAtPoint(e.getPoint()));
        table.setColumnSelectionInterval(clickedIndex, clickedIndex); //selects which column will have all its rows selected
        table.setRowSelectionInterval(0, table.getRowCount() - 1); //once column has been selected, select all rows from 0 to the end of that column
    }
});
```

Comment: @zx485 What else would you add?

Answer (score 1):

I created a method setColumnSelect having a parameter - JTable. 
 This method adds addMouseListener to JTable and JTableHeader. 
 If first column header is clicked then all table cells are selected. 
 If any other column header is clicked then entire column is selected. 
 If any cell is clicked then only that cell is selected. 
 If any cell of first column is clicked / double -clicked then only that entire row is selected. 
 After selecting the entire column and dragging the mouse over the cells of other columns makes those columns entirely selected. 
 After selecting a single row and dragging mouse over rows makes other rows entirely selected.

```
public void setColumnSelect(JTable table) {
    final JTable finalTable = table;
    final JTableHeader columnHeader = finalTable.getTableHeader();

    //For Row Selection

    finalTable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
            finalTable.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
            finalTable.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);

            if (finalTable.isCellSelected(finalTable.getSelectedRow(), 0)) {
                finalTable.setColumnSelectionAllowed(false);
                finalTable.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);                    
            }

        }
    });

    //For Column Selection

    columnHeader.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
            columnPoint =  columnHeader.columnAtPoint(mouseEvent.getPoint());

            columnCursorType = columnHeader.getCursor().getType();

            if (columnCursorType == Cursor.E_RESIZE_CURSOR)
                mouseEvent.consume();
            else {

                if (columnPoint == 0) //the very first column header
                    finalTable.selectAll(); //will select all table cells
                else {
                    finalTable.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
                    finalTable.setRowSelectionAllowed(false);
                    finalTable.clearSelection();
                    finalTable.setColumnSelectionInterval(columnPoint, columnPoint);
                }

            }
        }
    });

}
```