# How to select a column of a JTable in JDialog by selecting a header

Tags: java, swing, jtable, selection, jtableheader

[image]

What I've been trying to do with a `JDialog` are...

1. To select a column of `JTable` by clicking the header
2. To check which column is selected by the user
3. To get the value of the cells inside the column

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20265858/how-to-select-a-jtable-column-on-selection-of-header-in-java) and [this page](https://github.com/aterai/java-swing-tips/blob/master/ColumnSelection/src/java/example/MainPanel.java#L49) , it would be possible to select a column by clicking the header, by setting a `JTableHeader`.

However, neither of them seem to be applicable to what I'm trying to do.

First of all, I'm not sure where to put `JTableHeader`. The examples above seem to have put it for the initialization, but I don't see any appropriate space to do this in my coding.

At least I know that the second example is `JPanel`.  So, in order to have a `JTableHeader` in `JDialog`, `JTableHeader` will need to be set in a completely different position, since `initComponents()` of JDialog cannot be modified manually by default.

In addition, I cannot find how to select a header (unlike individual cells). I assume that I need to set a `JTableHeader` beforehand.

Finally, I don't see any method to detect which column is selected. At least I found `jTable.getValueAt(int, int)` method, but this method seems to be made to get a single cell.

Now I suspect that it might be impossible to do them with JTable and JDialog. I'd appreciate if you'd give any insight.

I add a part of `initComponents()` so that you'd easily understand it.

```
private void initComponents() {

    //here are irrelevant codes
    jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("MS UI Gothic", 3, 18)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setText("Choose level(s) or unit(s)");

    //irrelevant codes

    jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {
            {"EN6", "EN3", "EN5", "IN1"},
            {"EN2", "EN3", null, "IN4"},
            {null, null, null, "IN1"},
            {null, null, null, "IN2"},

        new String [] {
            "EN2", "EN3", "EN5", "IN1"
        }
    ) {
        Class[] types = new Class [] {
            java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class
        };
public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return types [columnIndex];
        }
    });
//lots of lines, seem to be irrelevant
pack();
}
```

Comment: I think you are looking for jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(x,y) and related functions.

Comment: selection is settable, there are options for row, column and cell selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"[...]it would be possible to select a column by clicking the header, by setting a JTableHeader."*

Based on your requirements I don't think you need to provide your own table header but attach a [MouseListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) to the default one instead. This way and using both rows and columns selection models you can easily achieve your goal.

#### Snippet

```
final JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);
table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
table.getTableHeader().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        // Get the right column based on MouseEvent#getPoint()
        int columnIndex = table.columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());
        // Set this column as the selected one in the columns selection model
        table.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(columnIndex, columnIndex);
        // Set all the rows as the selected ones in the rows selection model
        table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(0, table.getRowCount() - 1);
        // Print the values in selected column
        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < table.getRowCount(); rowIndex++) {
            System.out.println(table.getValueAt(rowIndex, columnIndex));
        }
    }
});
```

**Note:** don't forget to allow columns selection.

See:

- [MouseEvent#getPoint()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#getPoint--)
- [JTable#columnAtPoint(Point p)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#columnAtPoint-java.awt.Point-)
- [JTable#rowAtPoint(Point p)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#rowAtPoint-java.awt.Point-)
- [How to Use Tables: User Selections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#selection)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the select cell's value using this. But is that right you want?

```
table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        if (arg0.getClickCount() == 1) { // 1 : one click, 2 : double click, 3 : right click

            int column = table.getSelectedColumn();

            int row = table.getSelectedRow();
            String str = (String) table.getValueAt(row, column);

            int[] rows = table.getSelectedRows();
            String str2 = (String) table.getValueAt(rows[0], column);
        }
    }
});
```